# Is Black Pooka or Pooka Studio a bad name for a Graphic Design business?

Tags: logo, critique, branding, portfolio

I'm having a hard time deciding on a name. As of right now I'm going between Black Pooka and Pooka Studio. Is Pooka a good choice? Is it stupid?unprofessional? too obscure or confusing? Will I hate it when I'm 40? (I'm a 22 year old college student)

[This is a rough idea for a logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpOZT.png)

[image: Logo with the other name]

Comment: This is entirely opinion based and pretty much impossible to answer. I would say yes, call your business whatever you like, and this one is as good as any. A pluss is that it is "unusual", and some will say that is a good or a bad thing.

Comment: Don't be afraid to have a goofy name. I'm 37, and my business has been going by a rough translation of 'Idiots' in Japanese for some 10 years now.

Comment: @Vincent Baka Yaro Studios?!

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Almost. 'Bakabaka Design'.

Comment: Second @Vincent on that. I'm 42 and my company is called Cockypup. Seems to make clients smile (and giggle) which is always a good thing. If I would have called my company "ProDesign Trustable Inc" I think I would have hate it by now and I would have attracted the wrong clients.  My point is. What is the reasoning behind this name? What is your target market? The name and logo of your company will be your front sales person so you want make sure it represents you well. If you supply more info about the "why" then we can give objective opinions. Otherwise we are just being opinionated.

Answer (score 1):

I like Pooka Studio better. It provides context, signifying that this is a creative studio. It’s descriptive.

Are you referring to Celtic Mythology? If so, consider the alternate spelling “Púca” because it lends an air of sophistication. To me at least, “Pooka” looks a little child-like. Nothing wrong with that at all. But “Púca” seems the opposite: sophisticated and cultured and mysterious. And the accent is an awesome design element.

Branding is hard. Go with your gut.

Logo looks great.

Comment: I am referring to Celtic Mythology. The Pooka is almost my spirit animal lol. I'm going to play around with the spelling a little bit and see if I can use any of the other versions of it.

Answer (score -1):

Poo sounds kind of like, you know, poo.